# Colocar tabs dentro de um form

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um documento html com tabs. Isso está ok. Agora, dentro de uma dessas tabs, eu tenho um form, onde coloco meus controles. Não consegui colocar, dentro desse form mais tabs, de forma que teria um documanto e dentro dele duas tabs e dentro dessas tabs, mas controles em forms ou não.

A div tabs-2, já é uma tab, que faz parte da tab principal. Dentro dessa tab, eu tenho um form e dentro dele alguns controles. O que eu estou querendo é colocar mais duas tabs dentro desse form que está dentro de uma tab. Essa é a intenção, ou seja, a pergunta que não sei porque levou downvote. A subtab é que são as novas tabs para estarem dentro da tab principal. A posição das tabs deverão estar no final da página.

```
<div id="tabs-2">
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

       <div id="subtabs">
           <li><a href="#tabs-11">EventosPDV</a></li>
           <li><a href="#tabs-21">Minhas Tarefas</a></li>
       </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtCnpj" class="col-md-2 control-label">CNPJ:</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCnpj" placeholder="Digite o Cnpj">
        </div>
          <label for="imgStatus" class="col-md-2 control-label">Status:</label>
          <div class="col-md-2">
              <img src="~/Images/Certo.png" class="img-responsive col-md-4 control-label" id="imgStatus"/>
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblRazao" class="col-md-2 control-label">Razão Social:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRazaoSocial" placeholder="Digite a razão social">
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblIdEvento" class="col-md-2 control-label">ID Evento:</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtIdEvento" placeholder="Digite um evento">
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblDescricao" class="col-md-2 control-label">Descrição:</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="txtDescricao" placeholder="Digite uma descrição" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
           <label for="lblTipoEvento" class="col-md-2 control-label">Tipo Evento:</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <select class="form-control" name="ddlTipoEvento" id="ddlTipoEvento" >
              <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
                <option value="2">Acesso Remoto</option>
                <option value="8">Agendamento de Visita Técnica</option>
                <option value="6">Alteração de Cadastro</option>
                <option value="9">Ativar PDV</option>
                <option value="4">Contato Comercial</option>
                <option value="11">Contato Técnico</option>
                <option value="10">Inativar PDV</option>
                <option value="15">Instalação Extrator Cod. Interno</option>
                <option value="16">Processo 2</option>
                <option value="14">Processo Interno PDV</option>
                <option value="12">Sem Intervenção Técnica</option>
                <option value="1">Visita Técnica</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblAcao" class="col-md-2 control-label">Ação:</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <select class="form-control" id="ddlAcao" >
              <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
                <option value="2">Acesso Remoto</option>
                <option value="8">Agendamento de Visita Técnica</option>
                <option value="6">Alteração de Cadastro</option>
                <option value="9">Ativar PDV</option>
                <option value="4">Contato Comercial</option>
                <option value="11">Contato Técnico</option>
                <option value="10">Inativar PDV</option>
                <option value="15">Instalação Extrator Cod. Interno</option>
                <option value="16">Processo 2</option>
                <option value="14">Processo Interno PDV</option>
                <option value="12">Sem Intervenção Técnica</option>
                <option value="1">Visita Técnica</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <label for="lblUsuario" class="col-md-2 control-label">Usuário:</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <select class="form-control" id="ddlUsuario" >
              <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="lblUsuario" class="col-md-2 control-label">Usuário:</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
            </div>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Finalizar</button>
        </div>       

       <div id="tabs-11">
       </div>

       <div id="tabs-21">
       </div>

   </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Você pode colocar esses códigos aqui na pergunta?

Comment: Não, @pnet, ninguém quer que a pergunta esteja dentro dos padrões pessoais de cada um. Queremos que as perguntas estejam dentro do padrão do Stack Overflow, queremos que elas sejam concisas. Você falou muito sobre "tabs" que, para você, é espontaneamente simples porque você já sabe o que significa, mas para nós "tab" pode ser qualquer coisa – inclusive um plug-in que você esteja usando, e não o nome de uma classe. Portanto, se várias pessoas pensam que a pergunta não está clara, então ajude-nos a te ajudar.

Comment: Ok, de acordo, mas como eu chamaria tab? Não sei, não conheço outro nome para isso. Inclusive eu fiz uma vez uma pergunta aqui e não sabia como chamar, alguém me sugeriu tab. Em delphi eu usava a expressão TabSheet, mas no contexto do html é simplesmente tab, inclusive emlivros do mesmo assunto.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido. Criei uma função jquery para mais um conjunto de tabs:

```
$(function () {
    $("#subtabs").tabs();
});
```

E depois coloquei o meu html que vai criar as tabs na posição em eu quero as tabs. Com isso funcionou.

```
<div id="subtabs"style="border:none">
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#tabs-11">EventosPDV</a></li>
               <li><a href="#tabs-21">Minhas Tarefas</a></li>
           </ul>
......
</div>
```